# Windows scaling very slow when using remote deskop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I remote desktop to my workstation running Windows 10 Enterprise, it takes a while (30-45 seconds) for windows to become functional (read: taskbar takes a while to resize (scale), same with various windows that I have open).

I think this has to do with the fact that I am using a laptop with higher resolution screen (2K) to remote into the workstation where I was previously logged-on with only a Full HD resolution monitor.

Is there a way to speed it up somehow? It is very annoying for me to wait for 30-45 seconds after I connect using remote desktop.

Comment: Use a resolution that is identical to that of the workstation. Otherwise the image has to be interpolated, which takes time relative to the number of pixels. Afterwards, various optimizations may kick in, depending on the software, such as sending screen updates rather than the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm your internet speeds? this plays a huge part when remote desktop'ing and will cause input lag etc..

Why don't you use something free like Teamviewer, the reason I would advise this as you can 'optimise' for Quality or 'optimise' for Speed etc.

I would definitely recommend this.

Hope this helps